# Help in SQL query for beginners, max of column

Tags: query

I have 2 tables, one holds questions the other holds answers to the questions, each answer has a number of likes, I need to print each question with its most liked answer.
I have added a picture to show elaborate the question better.
[image]

the code I have written so far and does not work well:

```
SELECT q.q_text,a.a_text

FROM answers as a
JOIN questions AS q
on a.q_id = q.id

WHERE (SELECT max(answers.likes) from answers)
GROUP BY q.id;
```

Comment: What doesn't work well about it?

Comment: `WHERE (SELECT max(answers.likes) from answers)` is invalid SQL to begin with. The WHERE clause requires a boolean expression, not a number

Answer (score 1):

This approach has a great problem, if you have two or more answers with the same number of likes, you would see both or more in the result set.

If you want only **one** answer per question, you have to define which answer you prefer
That would be best realized with another column, that would indicate the "best" from all the max likes.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE questions (
>   `Id` INTEGER,
>   `question_text` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO questions
>   (`Id`, `question_text`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'question 1'),
>   ('2', 'question 2');
>
> CREATE TABLE answers (
>   `Id` INTEGER,
>   `question_id` INTEGER,
>   `likes` INTEGER,
>   `answer_text` VARCHAR(19)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO answers
>   (`Id`, `question_id`, `likes`, `answer_text`)
> VALUES
>   ('11', '1', '3', 'question 1 answer 1'),
>   ('12', '1', '20', 'question 1 answer 2'),
>   ('13', '1', '5', 'question 1 answer 2'),
>   ('21', '2', '500', 'question 2 answer 1'),
>   ('22', '2', '10', 'question 2 answer 2'),
>   ('23', '2', '80', 'question 2 answer 3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     q.question_text, a.answer_text
> FROM
>     answers AS a
>         JOIN
>     questions AS q ON a.question_id = q.Id
> WHERE
>     a.id IN (SELECT 
>             id
>         FROM
>             answers
>         WHERE
>             (`question_id` , likes) IN (SELECT 
>                     `question_id`, MAX(likes)
>                 FROM
>                     answers
>                 GROUP BY `question_id`));
> ```
>
> ```
> question_text | answer_text        
> :------------ | :------------------
> question 1    | question 1 answer 2
> question 2    | question 2 answer 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9746dd2771737be5189878764af1ca24)*

Answer (score 0):

Short and optimized query on SQL Server:

```
Select
    A1.question_id,
    A1.answer_text
From answers A1
RIGHT JOIN
(
    Select
        question_id, Max(Likes) as likes
    From answers 
    Group by question_id
) A2
ON A1.question_id=A2.question_id and A1.likes=A2.likes
RIGHT JOIN questions Q
ON Q.Id = A1.question_Id;
```

Result:

[image]